# Can't receive Firebase data messages in background Xamarin.iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have setup firebase cloud messaging in my Xamarin iOS app successfully. When I send messages via the firebase console, everything works fine.
On my backend, I added Firebase admin SDK for dotnet, and tried sending "data" messages to my iOS app in this way:

FIrst, using normal messages to topics:

```
var iOSMsg = new Message()
            {
                Topic = iOSDemoUsersTopic,
                Apns = new ApnsConfig
                {
                    Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "priority", "high" }
                    },
                    Aps = new Aps
                    {
                        ContentAvailable = true,
                        MutableContent = true
                    }
                },
                Data = notificationData.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value.ToString())
            };
        var response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);
```

This approach didn't work. Since I receive messages only when my app is open, when it goes I close it, notifications are not received anymore.

I then decided to try old Multicast messages, hopping it will work. I did as follows:

```
 var msg = new MulticastMessage
            {
                Apns = new ApnsConfig
                {
                    Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "priority", "high" }
                    },
                    Aps = new Aps
                    {
                        ContentAvailable = true,
                        MutableContent = true,
                    }
                },
                Data = notificationData.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value.ToString()),
                Tokens = iOSTokens.ToList()
            };

            var response = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendMulticastAsync(msg);
```

But, the thing still behaves the same way.
On android, I can receive messages in background and when the app is killed when they are data messages. I have tried a million things, please can someone help ?

Comment: Make sure that you had override the method `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` .Invoked `completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);` in the method .

Comment: Thanks, but I did that already. and it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution.
My notifications where sent well, but when gotten by iOS, the `alert` object of `aps` was not found, so the OS couldn't display the notification.

To make this property available, the **"Notification"** property too should be set in the message.

```
  var msg = new Message
            {
                Apns = new ApnsConfig
                {
                    Aps = new Aps
                    {
                        ContentAvailable = true,
                        MutableContent = true,
                    }
                },
                Notification = new Notification
                {
                    Body = body,
                    Title = title
                },
                Data = notificationData.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value.ToString()),
                Topic = iOSDemoUsersTopic
            };
```

So, after adding the notification property, everything went fine.